# WebAuthn exclude pin from options

Tags: webauthn

I'm implememting WebAuthn for my web app. I have a fingerprint reader (I can give you the model number if needed - it says it supports WebAuthn, FIDO etc) which I want to use to authenticate. The problem is that the PIN option is also available (might be related to Windows Hello), but I don't want that. I only want the fingerprint option. I tried setting the `authenticatorSelection.authenticatorAttachment` to `cross-platform`, but I get an error saying: "This security key can't be used. Please try a different one". The fingerprint reader is connected via USB.

What can I do so that I only give the fingerprint option to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put there is no mechanism in WebAuthn to only allow for biometric user verification.

The general thinking here is, the PIN is the protection for local biometric enrollment to then perform future biometric authentication. Therefore biometric-only auth doesn't make sense because if an attacker gets your PIN then they can enroll their fingerprint and then perform biometric authentication.

Comment: Can't believe you responded (I was reading some of your work the other days) .

Got it. Another question I have: is WebAuthn dependent on Windows Hello (on a Windows machine)?

Comment: Yes, typically "use WebAuthn on Windows" will involve Windows Hello no matter the browser. Some third-party "passkey providers" (1Password, Bitwarden, DashLane, etc...) use their browser extension to intercept and handle the WebAuthn request before it ever gets to Hello, which is the caveat to an otherwise simple "yes" answer here 